# Diagonalizing a Unitary Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to diagonalize the following unitary matrix:

$$\frac {1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2 \\ 2i &-i
\end{pmatrix}$$

My approach is to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in the usual way. However, no matter what I do, this is not yielding me the correct eigenvalues.

By doing the usual algebra (using $\det(A - kI) = 0$ where $k$ is the eigenvalue), I get the following equation quadratic in $k$:

$$k^2 + \frac {i-1}{\sqrt{5}}k - i = 0$$

I then solve this quadratic equation for $k$ using the quadratic formula with $a = 1, b = \frac {i-1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $c = -i$. This gives me a pair of conjugate eigenvalues. However, they are not the correct eigenvalues!

I just wonder if my approach is incorrect. Is there a way to easily diagonalize a unitary matrix with complex entries, by using the fact that it is unitary? I know a unitary matrix will have orthogonal eigenvectors, eigenvalues of modulus 1, etc. But none of that really helps me in actually finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Your approach and your characteristic equation are correct. Perhaps you solved the equation wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. [Here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%281/sqrt%5B5%5D%29%7B%7B1,2%7D,%7B2I,-I%7D%7D&x=0&y=0) is the actual diagonalization via Wolfram Alpha.